# Twilio Chat - getChannelBySid is very slow for 100 channels

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using Twilio Chat Javascript SDK.

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.3/docs/Client.html#getChannelBySid__anchor

This function is very slow when the user is part of 100 channels. This takes around 6-7 seconds to return channel information.

Interestingly if I remove all the sessionStorage items related to twilio and reload the page, the same function takes around 1-2 seconds.

Any help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, how did you resolve this issue? I am currently having the same issue right now.

Comment: we removed the members from the channel when they are not active. this is to keep the user participation to only a few channels.